# When to use country code as well as language code

Tags: java, android, localization

I am interested to know why I should specify the country code as well as the language code when localising my apps? Im sure there is a valid reason but hours of Googling has not made this obvious. Surely language code alone covers all bases?
Thanks
Jason

Comment: the idea behind it is, that you're able to establish a hierarchy of locales, like de for German can be specified to German German (de_DE) and Suisse German (de_CH) as they share the same language except for some words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some differences between countries even if they share the same basic language. Those differences can be as small as spelling (color [AE] vs. colour [BE]), different words (trunk [AE] vs. boot [BE] in cars) or even completely different sentences since forms of expressing something politely might differ.

If those differences don't matter, just use the language only code.

Comment: Thank you very much. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to only use language code, if you need to be very specific you can also use country code - http://www.olat.org/docu/i18n/ch01s02.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you can give me cast-iron guarantee that your application will only *ever* deal with the language aspect of localization, this is fine - with the proviso, as Kai said above, that some dialects are the same language but have local idioms - German spoken in Germany is not the same as (but is mostly compatible with) German spoken in Austria; and again different to German spoken in Switzerland.

If your application is going to require any other localization (currency, time/calendar, address formats, language idioms), then you should be at least storing the country code, even if you don't need it yet.

Answer (score 0):

For example, **zh** means Chinese, but it has **Simplified Chinese** used by China mainland and **Traditional Chinese** used by Taiwan or Hongkong. Not only glyphs, the translations of many loadwords may also differ.

Answer (score 0):

Four Examples:

- Mexican Spanish can be a bit different from Spainish from Spain

  Brazil Portuguese can be a bit different from Portugal Portuguese

  American English can be a bit different from British English

  Canadian French can be a bit different than French French

In the case of your app, these differences may...or may not...matter.  It depends on the app.  You may not realize that your translation needs different localized versions until later when specific situations come up.